# What is the correct/proper Collection to use with java.nio.file.Path?

Tags: java, collections, nio

Much like you wouldn't use a `Vector` for a list of Cat objects at a vet, but would instead use an `ArrayList`, you also wouldn't use an `ArrayList` for a list of key/value pairs but might opt for a `HashMap`.

What is the correct choice for Path?

In case anyone finds this, I found this:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/performance-java-collections

It has performance benchmarks of ArrayList, HashMap, and LinkedList. Very useful to see the exact differences in the various situations.

Comment: Depends on your logic.

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I'm hoping for a standards-based answer, but if it comes down to logic, then please make your case

Comment: Sort em, random access, millions of "instances"

Comment: Well what are you trying to *do* with these paths? `ArrayList` has pretty much superceded `Vector` as a container in all cases; that has nothing to do with the `Cat` objects. You'd use a `Map` if you want a key/value relationship... if you just want a collection of `Path` instances which you're going to access by index, then an `ArrayList` is fine... whereas if you want to map from `String` to a path, then again a `Map` would be appropriate. It's *all* about what you want from the collection.

Comment: @JonSkeet Since `Vector`s are *synchronized*, wouldn't you use them sometimes? When you really need methods to be synchronized?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun: In that case I'd probably use `Collections.synchronizedList` - which would emphasize that aspect.

Comment: *"Sort em, random access, millions of "instances""* - That is not sufficient information for making a recommendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no single correct answer to this.  Rather you should get an understanding of the different Collection types (classes, interfaces) and pick one that suits the *specific* requirements of the *specific* code you are trying to implement.

AFAIK, there is nothing special about `Path` that changes the decision making process.

---

> I'm hoping for a standards-based answer ...

That's a cop out!  Just like asking what is "best practice".

(Hint: "best practice" is to understand the APIs and make a rational / reasoned decision for yourself!)

---

> Is there a standard collection for Path?

Nope.  There are *lots* of standard Java collection classes and interfaces that *could* be used with `Path` ... and there is nothing about `Path` to make any of them preferable over the others (independently of the use-case).